# TImage not showing when adding an additional image to TTabSheet at runtime

Tags: delphi-xe7

I have a desktop program that has a modal from (`FirearmForm`) that has a `TPageControl` with 5 `TTabSheet`s.

On TabSheet 3, I paint bmp files that are stored in a database (SQL Server). The following code is executed in the `OnShow` event of the tabsheet. It paints all the images perfectly.

There is a button to add a new record with a new picture. I click the button, get a modal form to select a pic, and add it to the database with no problems. I automatically close that modal form. I then call the `Refresh` method for the TabSheet containing the images.

Running in debug mode, I see it use the code shown to rebuild the images, including the new image just uploaded. BUT .... the TabSheet continues to show the original images **only**, just as when the TabSheet was "shown" the first time. If I click on another TabSheet and then click back to the sheet containing the images, the code executes again, but the new image is not shown (the originals still do). If I click to another tab a second time and then click back to the images tab, the new images (and all the others) are shown correctly.

What am I doing wrong?  Any ideas why I have to run through that code twice before it works as required?

I have tried several different methods of building the `TImage`s and the results are always the same. Any ideas from someone smarter than me?

PS .. I've tried the `Create` method of the `TImage` as (self) and with a form name ... same effect.

```
procedure TFirearmForm.tsInPicturesShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  wkFileName, wkAName : string;
  wkPic : tPicture;
  wkJPG : tJPEGImage;
  wkBMP : tBitMap;
  wkImg : tImage;
  I, x, wkTop, wkLeft : integer;
  wkComp : tComponent;

begin

  with dm.qryDocuments do begin
    close;
    sql.Text := 'select d.*, di.DocumentBitMap from documents d ' +
      'join DocumentImages di on ' +
        'di.CompanyId=d.CompanyId and ' +
        'di.DocumentId=d.DocumentId ' +
      'where ' +
      'd.companyid=' + quotedstr(dm.gCompanyId) + ' and ' +
      'd.adnumber='  + quotedstr(dm.gADNumber);
    open;

    I := 0;
    wkTop := 32;
    wkLeft := 46;

    while not eof do begin
      inc(i);
      wkAName := 'InImage' + fieldbyname('DocumentId').AsString;

      wkComp := FirearmForm.pcFirearm.findcomponent(wkAName);
      if assigned(wkComp) then begin
        next;
        continue;
      end;

      wkImg := TImage.Create(FirearmForm.pcFirearm);

      wkImg.Parent  := tsInPictures;
      wkImg.Left    := wkLeft;
      wkImg.Top     := wkTop;
      wkImg.Name    := wkAName;
      wkImg.Picture.assign(fieldbyname('DocumentBitMap') as tBlobField);
      wkImg.Visible := True;

      wkLeft := wkLeft + 184;
      if i > 2 then begin
        if i mod 6 = 0 then begin
          wkTop := wkTop + 180;
          wkLeft := 46;
        end;
      end;

      next;
    end;
  end;

//  FirearmForm.pcFirearm.ActivePageIndex :=2;

end;
```

Comment: You did not show the code that adds new records to the DB. But offhand, it sounds like maybe your record is not actually being committed to the DB when you need it to be. Are you using any DB transactions?

Comment: On a side note, you should not be using the global `FirearmForm` pointer while inside a method of the `TFirearmForm` class. Use the `Self` pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Remy .. the record is indeed in the database. I've been programming for 35 years and know how to commit a rec to a DB.  I dont understand your second comment. When I use the "self" pointer it still exhibits the same behavior ... two clicks away and it displays ok.